# Access IBOutlet in animation block in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation, block, fatal-error

I am using this lines for animating a uiview in Swift.
I am getting an error like

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

```
UIView.transitionFromView(viewFront, toView: viewBack, duration: 0.7, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromLeft) { (boool) -> Void in

  self.viewFront.hidden = !self.viewFront.hidden
  self.viewBack.hidden = !self.viewBack.hidden

}
```

Comment: Which method are you calling this code from ?

Comment: On button Click i am calling the above  code.

Comment: If it's inside button click action it's probably related to some unproperly set IBOutlet please see @Rob answer below it should solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Examine `viewFront` and `viewBack` and see if either is `nil`. If so, the most common sources of this problem are:

- failure to hook up the outlets correctly; this can be visually identified by looking at the code; in the following example, `viewFront` outlet is not connected correctly (as indicated by the empty circle in the left margin), whereas `viewBack` is connected:

  [image]

  Or go to the storyboard, select the view in question, and look at the connections inspector in the right panel:

  [image]
- instantiating the view controller incorrectly (e.g. using `ViewController()` rather than `storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("StoryboardID")`